# gvim previous command issued in compatible mode

Tags: windows, vim

in regular "nocompatible" mode
 I just use the `<up>` key to get previous command issued
how can i get it in "compatible" mode.

looked the help files and couldn't find it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious: why compatible mode?

Comment: @ulidtko I'm using windows and I can't use <ctrl-v> or <ctrl-a> like they are defined. for example

Comment: ?? It's no excuse. Most of the time I use gvim under windows, and definitively never in compatible mode. Moreover, just delete mswin.vim, no sane vimmer want to use this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim help, if you try `:help cmdline-history`

It says at the end :

```
{Vi: no history}
{not available when compiled without the |+cmdline_hist| feature}
```

So I don't think that in compatible mode you can access a previous typed command easily.

You can actually get the last command stored in the command register.

To retype the latest command :

- Type `:` to go in command mode
- Type  `<C-r>` then `:`, it will paste the content of the `":` register

(The last command will also work in insert mode)

Answer (score 3):

For issuing previous `:command`, try `@:`

If you mean repeating *normal* mode commands, `.` is your friend.

Comment: @Gord, and this isn't specific to vim; I use `!!` and `!prefix` in shell all the time.

Comment: Also there is funny anecdote related to `!!` in shell. If you issue some command (say `apt-get install something`), bug forget `sudo`, you may say `sudo !!` on next line — and now it will work OK .`:)`

Comment: Though it is not specific to vim, `!!` is expanded by vim before shell is invoked, so there are lots of differencies (though I'd prefer shell expansion of !!: at least it won't happen inside `''`).